# Активность кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток, Товарищи!!
В общем у меня  такая проблема: когда открываю страничку, то у меня в 1 вопросе уже сразу выбран 1й  `radio`, а как сделать, чтобы  он был не выбранным как во втором вопросе, у меня не получается.

И где косяк - не могу найти.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <title>Тест</title> 
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#form_S {background-color: #00AA00}
-->

</style>

<script language="javascript">  
function check1()
{ 
 var i=0; 
var s=2;  
 if  (document.form1.otv1.value=="P")  {i++}; 
 if  ((document.form1.otv21.checked) & (document.form1.otv23.checked) & (document.form1.otv24.checked)) 
  {  i++};
  var r=i/s*100;
  alert(r); 
    }
</script>
</head> 
 <body id="form_s">
 <form name="form1" id="form_s" onsubmit="check1()">
<textarea name="vopros1" cols="40" rows="5">
Атрибут это: 
</textarea> 
<br>
    <input type="radio" name="otv1" value="параметр или свойство элемента" checked>параметр или свойство элемента<br>
    <input type="radio" name="otv1" value="фрагмент текста, который является указателем на другой файл или объект.">фрагмент текста, который является указателем на другой файл или объект.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="otv1" value="область документа, со своими полосами прокрутки, или одиночное изображение в сложном графическом файле.">область документа, со своими полосами прокрутки, или одиночное изображение в сложном графическом файле.<br>
    <input type="radio" name="otv1" value="документ, созданный в виде текста с расширением .HTML или . HTM">документ, созданный в виде текста с расширением .HTML или . HTM<br>
<textarea name="vopros2" cols="40" rows="5">
Апплет это:
</textarea>
<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otv21" value="программа, включенная в состав Web-страницы для расширения ее возможностей"> программа, включенная в состав Web-страницы для расширения ее возможностей<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otv22" value="программа, передаваемая на компьютер клиента в виде отдельного файла и запускаемая при просмотре Web-страницы">программа, передаваемая на компьютер клиента в виде отдельного файла и запускаемая при просмотре Web-страницы<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otv23" value="область документа, со своими полосами прокрутки, или одиночное изображение в сложном графическом файле">область документа, со своими полосами прокрутки, или одиночное изображение в сложном графическом файле<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="otv24" value="фрагмент текста, который является указателем на другой файл или объект."> фрагмент текста, который является указателем на другой файл или объект.<br>
<br>    
<input type="submit" value="Проверка" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

И еще такой косяк, при нажатии кнопки проверка - выдает "0", при любом ответе, а как сделать, чтобы он показывал правильно/неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из первого input-а убрать атрибут **checked**.

Comment: О, спасибо, проморгал, а как сделать, чтобы он говорил правильно/неправильно? а не "0" светил?

Comment: Для проверки ответов, нужно их с чем-то сверять. Или же сделать массив правильных ответов, или сразу в функции проверять. 

    if(document.form.otv1[0].checked) {i++;}

Comment: Черт.. Я сделал как вы сказали, но теперь он делает так:   ПРи    ответе правильно  на вопросы  он говорит "50", а если неправильно, то "0". Всё таки  хотелось, чтобы он не числами мне отвечал..